# How to echo a ' in php

Tags: php, javascript, echo, alert

I am trying to echo a javascript alert message in php but I am having problems with enclosing the ''s of the alert inside the '''s of the php.

The code looks like this >>

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?')"
```

If I use

```
echo onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?')"
```

I get errors in dreamweaver on that line because of the extra ''s , if I use

echo  'onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?")"';

I no longer get errors in php, but it still doesn't work and the html produced gives me a duplicate attributes message because of the extra ""s it produces once it is outputted.

Comment: `$str = <<<TEST  ... <newline>TEST;echo $str;`. Or replace `'` with `\'`. Or use `&quot;` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
echo('onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?\')"');
```

Comment: Hi, When I use this I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: well, that may be, but it's not due to this line of script - check it here, works like a charm http://codepad.viper-7.com/MkJqHP - the error tells you that you have some syntax error, it should also tell you the line and the file, so look at it there...

Comment: glad to been of help, thanx for the accept - why the downvote? :)

Answer (score 3):

there is not a single reason for *echoing* Javascript from PHP
Just close PHP tag and write your JS as is

```
?>
<a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?')">
```

easy-peasy

Comment: @ycs - (for my interest) why? this makes the code always look so ugly in my opinion so I always echo it too...

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about. (D)HTML never looks ugly when properly highlighted/indented and especially without unnecessary escaping.

Comment: @ycs - POV, I use DW and I don't like how php/html highlighting looks when you combine it... maybe just a bad habit I have... however - is there a particular technical reason why it's not OK to echo the JS?

Comment: there is no technical reason, just a usability. it is always OK to work with JS as JS, not as some anonymous blob inside of PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

When you echo out with nested quotes you need to be careful of how you quote.

When you wrap everything in quotes you have you escape the duplicates inside with \

Examples:

```
<?php
    echo " onclick=\" alert(1); \" ";
    echo ' onclick=\' alert(1); \' ';
?>
```

When you use both types of quotes you must also escape the duplicates inside of each other with \
Examples:

```
<?php
    echo 'onclick="return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?\")"';
    echo 'onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?\')"';

    echo "onclick='return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?\')'";
    echo "onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?\")'";
?>
```

You can use `&quot;` to replace " and `&#39;` to replace ' in the html but you must be mindful of your quote structure within the html! 
For example this will work...

```
<?php
     echo 'onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this customer ?&#39;)"';
?>
```

But using `&quot;` instead of `&#39;`  above would cause problems because the onclick in the html would have unescaped nested quotes.

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
  <?php
      printf('<script>confirm("are u sure to delete this customer ?");</script>');
  ?>
```